# Asterisk ARI. Получение записей

Tags: asterisk

Пытаюсь получить записи звонков с астериска через ARI. Использую веб сервис http://ari.asterisk.org. Получаю следующий ответ: `{ "error": "Allocation failed" }`. В консоли астериска получаю следующее сообщение: Error opening directory - /var/spool/asterisk/recording: No such file or directory.

Записи лежат в следующем каталоге: `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2017/09/01`. В данном каталоге три файла: `internal-100-101-082422-1504232662.0.wav`, `internal-цифры-те-же.2.wav`, `internal-цифры-те-же.4.wav`.

Информацию о астериске через ARI получаю, а вот с записями проблемы возникли. Может я конфигурацию не так выполнил?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема заинтересовала меня, поэтому я решил поэкспериментировать на своем **Asterisk 13.4.0** и пришел к следующим выводам.

Судя по вашей ошибке:

```
/var/spool/asterisk/recording: No such file or directory.
```

у вас вообще нет этой директории. Но при тестировании на моей системе, при удалении этой папки, возникла ошибка(возможно ответ в зависимости от версии может быть другим):

```
Error reading dir '/var/spool/asterisk/recording'
```

В общем система сканирует директорию(и только её) на предмет аудио записей:

```
/var/spool/asterisk/recording
```

У вас там ничего нет, но это легко поправить двумя способами.

1. Перелить все файлы и переделать конфиг на запись в директорию **recording**.
2. Удалить директорию **recording** и создать **symlink** вот так:

   ln -s /var/spool/asterisk/monitor /var/spool/asterisk/recording

или на любую другую где лежат ваши записи.

Вы можете подумать, что можно просто запихнуть в директорию **recording** ссылку на **monitor** или на аудио файлы, но возникнет ошибка:

```
Skipping /var/spool/asterisk/recording/ivr.wav: not a regular file
```

В итоге после данных манипуляций вы получите:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8088/ari/recordings/stored?api_key=login:password

[
  {
    "name": "2017/background",
    "format": "mp3"
  },
  {
    "name": "ivr",
    "format": "wav"
  }
]
```

**-=Обновление=-**

В результате дальнейших исследований выяснилось что все-таки необходимо придерживаться варианта номер **1**. 
Причина в том, что, способ номер **2** позволял только прочитать содержимое папки **recordings**, но к сожалению, для чтения или удаления непосредственно записи не подходит.

```
Request URL: recordings/stored/ivr.wav?api_key=login:pass
Response Body: "message": "Recording not found"
```

Покопавшись в дебрях астериска я обнаружил конфигурационные **json'ы** :

```
/var/lib/asterisk/rest-api
```

там обнаружил **recordings.json**.
В этом файле прописана конфигурация нужного нам API, URI, описания, какие-то параметры.
Я попытался заменить значение **path** в блоке для чтения содержимого каталога на **/outgoing/stored**, но это не принесло пользы, путь в **http://ari.asterisk.org** поменялся, а ресурс так и не был найден. А **recordings/stored** при этом работает.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался вторым способом и получил список аудио записей. Но при попытке получить конкретную (по имени): "localhost:8088/ari/recordings/stored/2017/09/01/internal-100-101-20170901-082422-1504232662.0?api_key=login:pass". Возникает следующее сообщение : {
  "message": "Resource not found"
} . Пробовал открыть полный доступ (chmod 0777) к папкам monitor и recording, но все безрезультатно.